# in magento 1.3.2 which file is responsible forstoring the data of payment gateway options like Mastercard visa AMEX?

Tags: magento

in magento 1.3.2 which file is responsible forstoring the data of payment gateway options like Mastercard visa AMEX?

pls help

Answer (score 1):

```
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml
```

Try not to change this file directly as that could get overwritten by updates. Instead use [Magento's modularity](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customize_part_of_configuration) to make changes safely.

Comment: To the OP: With more detail about what you're doing, there are people here who can even help you use that modularity!